# Issue with Tensorflow Kenlm

Tags: tensorflow, kenlm

How to install tensorflow with kenlm ?

Apparently while using tensorflows ctc beam search decoder there is no argument for kenlm. How can we integrate kenlm within that function ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not officially supported. However, there are external implementations of that. See e.g. [Mozilla DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech), [here](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/blob/8818874217bb5f4e1bd1aeeae23efd336fce87f9/native_client/beam_search.cc). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947619/using-custom-beam-scorer-in-tensorflow-ctc-language-model) for a related question.
Also, [RETURNN](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/blob/master/TFKenLM.py) provides a [TensorFlow wrapper for KenLM](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/blob/master/TFKenLM.py).